# Is it possible to use a logical OR, or negate a condition in Installshield 2012 PRQs?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2012

I have a PRQ that installs **MS SQL Shared Management Objects**. I have a condition that installs the PRQ if this registry key does not exist

```reg
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{08ECC740-2B3E-45D7-860C-59B511386286}
```

This works fine until a user has SMO installed with a different product code - this happens to our dev team all the time when they install SQL2008. The installer the PRQ starts exists with an error.

I need a better condition.  What I'd like to do is:
If (Version <= w.x.y.z || No Version found)
Then install PRQ

In the **InstallShield Prerequisite editor** it says

> The Following conditions must be met for the prerequisite to run. 
>   Here you can define files and registry keys that the prerequisite will
>   look for to determine if it should be run.  If there are no
>   conditions, the prerequisite will always run.

This agrees with my findings - the conditions are ANDed together.  Is there some unpublished sauce to OR or negate conditions in the XML?
I'm vexed right now because looking to run a prq if the version in the registry is < what I'm installing.

```xml
<conditions>
    <condition Type="32" Comparison="2" 
       Path="HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SharedManagementObjects\CurrentVersion" 
       FileName="Version" ReturnValue="10.1.2531.0">
    </condition>
</conditions>
```

Type="32" is 'A registry entry has a specified version value'
Comparison="2" is 'Data on target system is less than specified data'

Side question:  Is there a place where the Types and Comparisons are enumerated?

This Comparison type doesn't have a comparison to state 'Data on target system is less than specified data **or does not exist**'.  As it is now, if the key exists at a lower version things work - but if the key doesn't exist (i.e. SMO isn't installed) the PRQ isn't installed.

Is there a way to make this work?  The 'A file with certain version exists' condition does have a If the file's version is LESS THAN the version specified above (or the file IS NOT FOUND on the target system) option.   But it won't work to check a file installed by SMO - the user may have installed it to some drive other than C:.

I'm hoping I'm missing something.  What would you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I typically do is not use abstract things like ARP entries to detect the dependency. I go for the dependency itself.   If you need a DLL then look to see if the DLL is there instead of worrying about detecting something that should have installed the DLL.

Comment: But what if the user has installed the package in a non-standard location?

Comment: I think that DLL gets installed in the GAC regardless.  That should standardize your search.